# problem in run oracle server please help

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I used Oracle 11g, from few days ago I face below error:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu Apr 7 07:33:19 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: pentacms
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0


Enter user-name:
```

I try to solve the error, but it raised an other error, I try to open log file but I receive below error(last line) 
"ERROR at line 1:
    ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_nab_less_than_odr], [1],
    [46], [32689], [32690], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
    "
please advice me, It's an emergency case.

---

```
FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------------- ------------- -------------- --------------- -------------
TOP_LEVEL_CALL# LOGON_TIM LAST_CALL_ET PDM FAILOVER_TYPE FAILOVER_M FAI
--------------- --------- ------------ --- ------------- ---------- ---
RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP          PDML_STA PDDL_STA PQ_STATU
-------------------------------- -------- -------- --------
CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION
----------------------
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER                                                BLOCKING_SE
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCK FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE
----------------- ---------------- ----------- -----------------------
FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION       SEQ#     EVENT#
---------------------- ---------- ----------
EVENT
----------------------------------------------------------------
P1TEXT                                                                   P1
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P1RAW
----------------
P2TEXT                                                                   P2
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P2RAW
----------------
P3TEXT                                                                   P3
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P3RAW            WAIT_CLASS_ID WAIT_CLASS#
---------------- ------------- -----------
WAIT_CLASS                                                        WAIT_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SECONDS_IN_WAIT STATE               WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO
--------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------------
TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO
--------------------------
SERVICE_NAME                                                     SQL_TRAC SQL_T
---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
SQL_T SQL_TRACE_ SESSION_EDITION_ID CREATOR_ADDR     CREATOR_SERIAL#
----- ---------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------------
ECID
----------------------------------------------------------------
SYS$USERS                                                        DISABLED FALSE

SADDR                   SID    SERIAL#     AUDSID PADDR                 USER#
---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
USERNAME                          COMMAND    OWNERID TADDR
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------------
LOCKWAIT         STATUS   SERVER       SCHEMA# SCHEMANAME
---------------- -------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------
OSUSER                         PROCESS
------------------------------ ------------------------
MACHINE                                                                PORT
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
TERMINAL
----------------
PROGRAM                                                          TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SQL_ADDRESS      SQL_HASH_VALUE SQL_ID        SQL_CHILD_NUMBER SQL_EXEC_
---------------- -------------- ------------- ---------------- ---------
SQL_EXEC_ID PREV_SQL_ADDR    PREV_HASH_VALUE PREV_SQL_ID   PREV_CHILD_NUMBER
----------- ---------------- --------------- ------------- -----------------
PREV_EXEC PREV_EXEC_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------- ------------ --------------------- -------------------------
PLSQL_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------------- -------------------
MODULE                                           MODULE_HASH
------------------------------------------------ -----------
ACTION                           ACTION_HASH
-------------------------------- -----------
CLIENT_INFO
----------------------------------------------------------------
FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------------- ------------- -------------- --------------- -------------
TOP_LEVEL_CALL# LOGON_TIM LAST_CALL_ET PDM FAILOVER_TYPE FAILOVER_M FAI
--------------- --------- ------------ --- ------------- ---------- ---
RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP          PDML_STA PDDL_STA PQ_STATU
-------------------------------- -------- -------- --------
CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION
----------------------
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER                                                BLOCKING_SE
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCK FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE
----------------- ---------------- ----------- -----------------------
FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION       SEQ#     EVENT#
---------------------- ---------- ----------
EVENT
----------------------------------------------------------------
P1TEXT                                                                   P1
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P1RAW
----------------
P2TEXT                                                                   P2
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P2RAW
----------------
P3TEXT                                                                   P3
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P3RAW            WAIT_CLASS_ID WAIT_CLASS#
---------------- ------------- -----------
WAIT_CLASS                                                        WAIT_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SECONDS_IN_WAIT STATE               WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO
--------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------------
TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO
--------------------------
SERVICE_NAME                                                     SQL_TRAC SQL_T
---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
SQL_T SQL_TRACE_ SESSION_EDITION_ID CREATOR_ADDR     CREATOR_SERIAL#
----- ---------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------------
ECID
----------------------------------------------------------------
FALSE FIRST EXEC                  0 000007FF5D4D8D70               2

SADDR                   SID    SERIAL#     AUDSID PADDR                 USER#
---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
USERNAME                          COMMAND    OWNERID TADDR
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------------
LOCKWAIT         STATUS   SERVER       SCHEMA# SCHEMANAME
---------------- -------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------
OSUSER                         PROCESS
------------------------------ ------------------------
MACHINE                                                                PORT
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
TERMINAL
----------------
PROGRAM                                                          TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SQL_ADDRESS      SQL_HASH_VALUE SQL_ID        SQL_CHILD_NUMBER SQL_EXEC_
---------------- -------------- ------------- ---------------- ---------
SQL_EXEC_ID PREV_SQL_ADDR    PREV_HASH_VALUE PREV_SQL_ID   PREV_CHILD_NUMBER
----------- ---------------- --------------- ------------- -----------------
PREV_EXEC PREV_EXEC_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------- ------------ --------------------- -------------------------
PLSQL_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------------- -------------------
MODULE                                           MODULE_HASH
------------------------------------------------ -----------
ACTION                           ACTION_HASH
-------------------------------- -----------
CLIENT_INFO
----------------------------------------------------------------
FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------------- ------------- -------------- --------------- -------------
TOP_LEVEL_CALL# LOGON_TIM LAST_CALL_ET PDM FAILOVER_TYPE FAILOVER_M FAI
--------------- --------- ------------ --- ------------- ---------- ---
RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP          PDML_STA PDDL_STA PQ_STATU
-------------------------------- -------- -------- --------
CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION
----------------------
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER                                                BLOCKING_SE
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCK FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE
----------------- ---------------- ----------- -----------------------
FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION       SEQ#     EVENT#
---------------------- ---------- ----------
EVENT
----------------------------------------------------------------
P1TEXT                                                                   P1
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P1RAW
----------------
P2TEXT                                                                   P2
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P2RAW
----------------
P3TEXT                                                                   P3
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P3RAW            WAIT_CLASS_ID WAIT_CLASS#
---------------- ------------- -----------
WAIT_CLASS                                                        WAIT_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SECONDS_IN_WAIT STATE               WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO
--------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------------
TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO
--------------------------
SERVICE_NAME                                                     SQL_TRAC SQL_T
---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
SQL_T SQL_TRACE_ SESSION_EDITION_ID CREATOR_ADDR     CREATOR_SERIAL#
----- ---------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------------
ECID
----------------------------------------------------------------


SADDR                   SID    SERIAL#     AUDSID PADDR                 USER#
---------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ----------
USERNAME                          COMMAND    OWNERID TADDR
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------------
LOCKWAIT         STATUS   SERVER       SCHEMA# SCHEMANAME
---------------- -------- --------- ---------- ------------------------------
OSUSER                         PROCESS
------------------------------ ------------------------
MACHINE                                                                PORT
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
TERMINAL
----------------
PROGRAM                                                          TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SQL_ADDRESS      SQL_HASH_VALUE SQL_ID        SQL_CHILD_NUMBER SQL_EXEC_
---------------- -------------- ------------- ---------------- ---------
SQL_EXEC_ID PREV_SQL_ADDR    PREV_HASH_VALUE PREV_SQL_ID   PREV_CHILD_NUMBER
----------- ---------------- --------------- ------------- -----------------
PREV_EXEC PREV_EXEC_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_ENTRY_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------- ------------ --------------------- -------------------------
PLSQL_OBJECT_ID PLSQL_SUBPROGRAM_ID
--------------- -------------------
MODULE                                           MODULE_HASH
------------------------------------------------ -----------
ACTION                           ACTION_HASH
-------------------------------- -----------
CLIENT_INFO
----------------------------------------------------------------
FIXED_TABLE_SEQUENCE ROW_WAIT_OBJ# ROW_WAIT_FILE# ROW_WAIT_BLOCK# ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------------- ------------- -------------- --------------- -------------
TOP_LEVEL_CALL# LOGON_TIM LAST_CALL_ET PDM FAILOVER_TYPE FAILOVER_M FAI
--------------- --------- ------------ --- ------------- ---------- ---
RESOURCE_CONSUMER_GROUP          PDML_STA PDDL_STA PQ_STATU
-------------------------------- -------- -------- --------
CURRENT_QUEUE_DURATION
----------------------
CLIENT_IDENTIFIER                                                BLOCKING_SE
---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
BLOCKING_INSTANCE BLOCKING_SESSION FINAL_BLOCK FINAL_BLOCKING_INSTANCE
----------------- ---------------- ----------- -----------------------
FINAL_BLOCKING_SESSION       SEQ#     EVENT#
---------------------- ---------- ----------
EVENT
----------------------------------------------------------------
P1TEXT                                                                   P1
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P1RAW
----------------
P2TEXT                                                                   P2
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P2RAW
----------------
P3TEXT                                                                   P3
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
P3RAW            WAIT_CLASS_ID WAIT_CLASS#
---------------- ------------- -----------
WAIT_CLASS                                                        WAIT_TIME
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
SECONDS_IN_WAIT STATE               WAIT_TIME_MICRO TIME_REMAINING_MICRO
--------------- ------------------- --------------- --------------------
TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO
--------------------------
SERVICE_NAME                                                     SQL_TRAC SQL_T
---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- -----
SQL_T SQL_TRACE_ SESSION_EDITION_ID CREATOR_ADDR     CREATOR_SERIAL#
----- ---------- ------------------ ---------------- ---------------
ECID
----------------------------------------------------------------


16 rows selected.

SQL> desc dba_user;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object dba_user does not exist


SQL> desc dba_users;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object dba_users does not exist


SQL> desc v$user;
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object v$user does not exist


SQL> desc v$users
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object v$users does not exist


SQL> seleect * from dba_users;
SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "seleect * ..." - rest of line ignored.
SQL> select * from dba_users;
select * from dba_users
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01219: database not open: queries allowed on fixed tables/views only


SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_nab_less_than_odr], [1],
[46], [32689], [32690], [], [], [], [], [], [], []


SQL> alter database mount;
alter database mount
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01100: database already mounted


SQL> alter database mount;
```

Comment: If you need any other information please just ask i will provide for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a powerfailure on the storage. This caused corrupted online redolog file[s].
What you can try to do is to a normal recovery. This will ask for nonexisting archivelogfiles to be applied. Instead of the archives you can give the redolog files.
To find the redolog files:

```
select member from v$logfile;

recover database until cancel;
```

if you are lucky, you get recover successfully completed. If not, you can try to with nasty settings that allow for corrupted redo, corrupted undo etc. Not what you want if you don't know what you are doing.
If you are lucky, you are lucky, otherwise, trash the database, suffer pain for a while and start all over.